# How to use rxjs operator to get recent values in serveral time

Tags: angular, logging, error-handling, rxjs

I want to logger the error to the server in APP, but i need to ignore the logger if the same error logged in the previous several time(e.g. one minute).
[Here is a demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-te2ylt?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts). Now i use a Map() to save the error i have sended, and use `filter` to adjust to logger. Is there a better way to use rxjs operator to do the same thing.

Comment: There is `distinctUntilChanged` operator

Answer (score 1):

**The main issue here is that in RxJS it is hard to handle data accumulated over time.**
One way to solve this issue is to leave RxJS for that specific point and then go back to it.

```
sourceString = "Hello, It's me. I was wondering if after all these years you'd like to meet";
errorCache = new Map();
errorLogger$$= new Subject<string>();

interval(1000).pipe(
  map(v =>this.sourceString.slice(v % this.sourceString.length,(v % this.sourceString.length) + 1))
).subscribe(v => tryToErrorLog(v))

function tryToErrorLog(msg: string): {
  const alreadyHaveErrorLog = this.errorCache.get(msg);

  if (!alreadyHaveErrorLog) {
    return;
  }

  this.addError(msg);
}

function addError(msg: string): {
  this.errorCache.set(msg);
  this.errorLogger$$.next(msg);
}
```

**Explanation:**
You can then use your errorLogger$$ to handle your errors over time. Alternatively you could use the scan operator, but in the end it's always the same: You need a place where to store and compare your data (like here: tryToErrorLog and errorCache). In a scan it would be the accumulated value instead of a local variable.

**Similar Issues:**
If you have to add, delete values from an array/map over time.

**Possible solutions:**

- `scan + filter`
- `side-effects` (like you did with the map/localvariable/tap)
- `custom-operator` (Internally handle specific issues via `scan` or `side-effects` but wrapped into a `custom-operator`.
- `leave rxjs for the time of state` (Like its described above).

*TLTR: If you need to handle state over time, in my opinion escape rxjs at the point where you need it and go back to it after you finished your handle.*

Comment: Thank you for your idea. As i know, `distinctUntilChanged` operator can only compare with the previus one and only the previous one. I need to compare with all the values emitted in the last several time.

Comment: @zxhnear is your question answered? There are multiple ways provided to solve your problem.